# Java array doesn't work

Tags: java, arrays

Creating a code where the user enters the amount of seats they want, the row. When i did the program for just one row, it works perfectly. I HAVE NO idea why it doesn't work now. 
Like 0 idea. If anyone can help fix this i will be grateful.

The code of just one row is after the first.

Note: if i wasn't clear before, when the program is ran, it will only just ask for the amount of seats, and everything else just crashes/doesn't work. I seriously have no idea how to fix this.

**JavaApplication1**

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author ziyue
 */
public class JavaApplication1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the amount of people in your group, up to 6");
        int num = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the desiered row, A-E. Enter capitals.");
        String ROW = input.nextLine();

         int[] r = {};        
         int[] RowA = {0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0};
         int[] RowB = {0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0};
         int[] RowC = {0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0};
         int[] RowD = {0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0};
         int[] RowE = {0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0};                           
         int highest = num - 1;         
         String available = "";
         String booking = " ";

         if ("A".equals(ROW)) {
            r = RowA;
         }
         if ("B".equals(ROW)) {
            r = RowB;
         }         
         if ("C".equals(ROW)) {
            r = RowC;
         }         
         if ("D".equals(ROW)) {
            r = RowD;
         }         
         if ("E".equals(ROW)) {
            r = RowE;
         }         

         for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
             if (r[i] == 0) {
                 available = available + (i + 1);

             }

             if (available.length() > booking.length()) {
                 booking = available;


             }else if (r[i] == 1) {
                 available = "";

             }
         }                           
            if (num <= booking.length()) {
            char low = booking.charAt(0);
            char high = booking.charAt(highest);
            System.out.println("There are seats one the row " + ROW + "from " + low + " - " + high + ".");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The desired seat amount is not available. The maximum amount on Row is " + booking.length());
        }
    }

}
```

**JavaApplication2**

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.util.*;

public class JavaApplication2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the amount of people in your group, up to 6");
        int num = input.nextInt();

        if (num > 6) {
            System.out.println("You have exceeded the maximum amount of people allowed.");

        }

        int highest = num - 1;

        String available = "";
        String booking = " ";

        int[] RowA = {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1};

        for (int i = 0; i < RowA.length; i++) {
            if (RowA[i] == 0) {
                available = available + (i + 1);

            }

            if (available.length() > booking.length()) {
                booking = available;

            } else if (RowA[i] == 1) {
                available = "";

            }
        }


        if (num <= booking.length()) {
            char low = booking.charAt(0);
            char high = booking.charAt(highest);
            System.out.println("There are seats from " + low + " - " + high + ".");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The desired seat amount is not available. The maximum amount on Row is " + booking.length());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Soooo... what's the question exactly?

Comment: Well, why can't you have an array of array?

Comment: You've given a *lot* of code, and very little indication of exactly where it's going wrong. Try to cut down what's required to show what's going wrong, and you may well find that you find the answer yourself.

Comment: That's too many code to help you you need to give us a guide and some relevant part of your code, not the entirely application

Comment: Are you saying Java's array don't work, you that you can't use Java's array? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your input is incorrect.  You are assuming that the number and the letter are on different lines but that is not what your input does.

```
System.out.println("Enter the amount of people in your group, up to 6");
int num = input.nextInt();
// discard the rest of the first line and 
// expect the next input to be on the next line.
input.nextLine(); 

System.out.println("Please enter the desiered row, A-E. Enter capitals.");
String ROW = input.nextLine();
```

If you don't discard the end of the first line, the ROW will contain what you typed after the number on the first line.

If you stepped through your code in your debugger you would see that ROW is not what you expected, saving you allot of time.